# VBA: type mismatch in rs.findfirst

Tags: ms-access, vba, type-mismatch, findfirst

I have this code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblJobs", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.FindFirst "EmpNo=" & "'cbEmpNo.Value'" & " And " & "JobNo=" & "'cbJobNo.Value'"
```

and I've been getting type mismatch (removing the ' doesn't seem to help, nor does adding [] around EmpNo & JobNo).

in tblJobs both EmpNo & JobNo are defined as Long Integer.

cbEmpNo & cbJobNo are ComboBoxes with no control source. Their row source is a SQL query pulling EmpNo / JobNo from tblJobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine the string built by that code.  Here it is in the Immediate window:

```vb
? "EmpNo=" & "'cbEmpNo.Value'" & " And " & "JobNo=" & "'cbJobNo.Value'"
EmpNo='cbEmpNo.Value' And JobNo='cbJobNo.Value'
```

So the code asks `FindFirst` to find the first row where *EmpNo* is equal to the string *cbEmpNo.Value*.  But since *EmpNo* is Long Integer, that comparison triggers the type mismatch error.  The same issue applies to *JobNo*.

Build the string to include the values of those controls (*cbEmpNo* and *cbJobNo*) instead of their names, and don't include quotes around those values:

```vb
Dim strFind As String
strFind = "EmpNo=" & Me.cbEmpNo.Value & " And JobNo=" & Me.cbJobNo.Value
Debug.Print strFind ' <- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
rs.FindFirst strFind
```